# Proper handling hashmaps in SpringMVC + angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have AngularJS + SpringMVC project.
By GET method it returns list of entities, so i can use it for ng-repeat for printing object data(name, for example)
But lately i needed to use hashmap(key - object with fields, value - String)

This is part of code, that i used for Lists in angular

This is how object fills fields in list
`<input type="text" ng-model="currentItem.taskName" class="form-control">`

```
app.controller('mainController',function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.tasks = [];
$scope.currentItem = {};
$scope.currentView = 'allTasks';

$scope.refresh = function () {
   $http({
       method:"GET",
       url:"/task"
   }).then(function (result) {
       $scope.tasks = result.data;
   });
};
$scope.refresh();

$scope.save = function(){
    $http({
        method:"PUT",
        url:"/task",
        data:$scope.currentItem,
        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content")}
    }).then(function(result) {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tasks.length; i++){
            if(result.data.id===$scope.tasks[i].id){
                $scope.tasks.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        $scope.tasks.push(result.data);
    });
    $scope.cancel();
};
```

now i had this controller:

```
@GetMapping
    public Map<TaskEntity,String> findAll(){
        user  = (UserEntity) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return taskService.findFromUser(user.getId());
    }
```

but it seems like didn't work.
angular can't find fields of object, when i use
`ng-repeat="(k,v) in tasks"
{{k.name}}`

but prints this `k` as object name `TaskEntity@3434h43`

So my question is: How to properly read hashmap, and add items into it

Answer (score 0):

Which class is responsible for deserialize the object between the backend and the frontend?

If I was in your shoes, first I would print the result of the GET request in the console in order to check the structure returned by the server, because you are returning a complex structure, and maybe it is rendered not as you are expecting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Jackson, so no, i don't think that it's problem. Between in the list it's all ok